One-hot-encoded table to tbl_summary
I have a one-hot-encoded tibble that contains the occurrence of certain arteries to in specific tumours. These can be divided in 2 groups: primary and secondary.
If there would be only 1 occurrence for every vessel possible per tumour, I would have no problem. However, some vessels have the same name (for example 1 for left and 1 for right side) and can occur 2 times per tumour.
To simplify the problem:
test <- tibble(
  group = c("primary", "secondary", "secondary", "primary"),
  common_carotid = as.numeric(c(1, 2, 0, 0)),
  internal_carotid = as.numeric(c(0, 1, 0, 1))
)

test |>
    tbl_summary(
      by = group,
      missing = "no"
    ) %>%
    add_p() %>%
    modify_header(label ~ "**Vessel**")

Gives

I would like to have a tbl_summary where common_carotid would show as 1 row like this but then with the correct numbers:

The desired output is:
| Vessel           | Primary, N=2 | Secondary N=3 | p-value |
| Common_carotid   | 1 (50%)      | 2 (67%)       | >0.9    |
| internal_carotid | 1 (50%)      | 1 (33%)       | >0.9    |

I was able to create this table changing the value of 2 in the common_carotid group to 1.
It seems that gtsummary treats these variables als factors and show the different levels although I tried to correct this to numbers.
It seems like a simple problem but who has the answer?
This is a part of the original data:
dput(head(data, 20))
structure(list(ID = c(23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 
33, 34, 35, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60), genesis_group = c("Secondary", 
"Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Primary", 
"Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Secondary", "Primary", 
"Secondary", "Secondary", "Primary", "Secondary", "Secondary", 
"Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary"), Arteries = structure(c(21L, 
96L, 39L, 79L, 96L, 32L, 59L, 79L, NA, 85L, 48L, 59L, 48L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 101L, 101L), levels = c("APA", "ASCA", 
"ASCA RA", "BCA", "DCA", "DCA RA", "DTA STA OA", "LAPA LOA", 
"LAPA RAPA RA", "LBCA", "LCCA", "LCCA LICA", "LCCA LICA LVA", 
"LDCA LOA", "LDCA LVA LASCA", "LDTA", "LECA", "LECA LSTA LEA REA LMMA", 
"LFA", "LIAA LSMA", "LICA", "LICA LMA", "LICA RECA", "LMA", "LMA LOA LSTA", 
"LMA LOPA DNA", "LOA", "LOA LAPA LDCA", "LOA LPAA LSTA", "LOA LSTA LEA", 
"LOA ROA LSTA RSTA", "LOPA", "LOPA LSTA", "LRA", "LSA", "LSA CCA", 
"LSOA RSOA RSTA LSTA", "LSPA", "LSTA", "LSTA LDTA", "LSTA LMA LMMA", 
"LSTA LOA", "LSTA LSTRA", "LSTA RSTA LSOA LPAA", "LSTA RSTA ROPA LOPA", 
"LSTHA", "LTT", "LVA", "LVA ECA", "LVA LECA", "MA", "OA", "OA PAA", 
"OA TT", "OPA", "PA", "RA", "RBCA", "RCCA", "RCCA RVA", "REA", 
"RECA", "RECA PAA", "RECA RFA", "RECA RSA RCCT RTT", "RFA", "RFA RMA", 
"RICA", "RICA RECA", "RITT", "RLA", "RMA", "ROA", "ROA RPAA", 
"ROA RSTA", "ROA RVA", "ROPA", "ROPA RMA", "RSA", "RSA TT", "RSCA", 
"RSOA", "RSOA RSTA", "RSPA", "RSTA", "RSTA LOA ROA", "RSTA LSTA", 
"RSTA RFA", "RSTA RMA RPAA", "RSTA ROA", "RSTA RPAA", "RSTHA", 
"RSUBLA ANGA", "RTA", "RTT", "RVA", "RVA ROA", "RVA RTT", "SLA", 
"STA", "STA OA", "STA OA OPA STA", "STA OPA", "STA PAA", "STA SOA", 
"TT", "VA", "VA APA DCA"), class = "factor"), Veins = c("LIJV", 
"RIJV", NA, "RIJV", "RVV", "LIOV", "REJV", "RSV", NA, NA, "LVV", 
"LIJV", "LIJV", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Identify all possible arteries and vessels entered using unique:
unique(sub('^[L|R]', '', data$Arteries))
# [1] "ICA"    "VA"     "STA"    "SA"     "OPA"    "CCA"    
# [2] NA       "STA OA"

unique(sub('^[L|R]', '', data$Veins))
#[1] "IJV" NA    "VV"  "IOV" "EJV" "SV"

Then reframe the data to create the columns you want to summarise using grepl, ignoring the L or R side:
data |> 
  reframe(
    #Arteries
    'Common carotid'=grepl("[L|R]?CCA", Arteries),
    'Internal carotid'=grepl("[L|R]?ICA", Arteries),
    'Superficial temporal'=grepl("[L|R]?STA", Arteries),
    'Venous'=grepl("[L|R]?VA", Arteries),
    'Sinoatrial'=grepl("[L|R]?SA", Arteries),
    'Ophthalmic'=grepl("[L|R]?OPA", Arteries),
    # Veins
    'Internal jugular'=grepl("[L|R]?IJV", Veins),
    'External jugular'=grepl("[L|R]?EJV", Veins),
    'Vascular'=grepl("[L|R]?VV", Veins),
    'Splenic'=grepl("[L|R]?SV", Veins),
    'Inferior orbital'=grepl("[L|R]?IOV", Veins),
    .by=genesis_group) |>
  tbl_summary(
    by = genesis_group,
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_p() %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Vessel**") |>
  modify_table_body(~ .x |>
                      bind_rows(tibble(
                        variable=c("Arteries","Veins"),
                        var_type=NA,
                        var_label=c("Arteries","Veins"),
                        row_type="label",
                        label=c("Arteries","Veins"),
                        stat_0= NA)
                      ) |>
   arrange(factor(variable, 
                  levels=c("Arteries",
                           "Common carotid",
                           "Internal carotid",
                           "Venous",
                           "Superficial temporal",
                           "Sinoatrial",
                           "Ophthalmic",
                           "Veins")))) |>
  modify_column_indent(columns=label,
                 rows=!variable %in% c("Arteries","Veins"))




Thank you for your answer. However it is important that these vessels are also counted as they are indeed feeders to the tumor. We can not discard them in our table…
I thought of dividing the rows of value 2 into 2 rows of value 1 but that messes up the percentages. I can also you pivot_long to make it a long dataset and turn the rows into columns however than the add_p() function does the statistic on only the name of the column and not per vessel. We can improve that with a add_stat() function and make our function but I didn’t manage to get that to work per vessel if these are subgroups…

Please clarify in your edited question how you want the output to appear for the example data.

Sorry for not being clear, I’ve edited the question and added a custom markdown table with the desired numbers.

See my edit using the new data.

You're a legend Edward, many thanks for this solution and tutorial!

The tbl_summary function expects case-by-case data, not a summarised one as you have. If you have the original data, use that. Otherwise, you can use the code below:
data <- test |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-group) |>
  mutate(n=ifelse(value==0, 1, value), 
         value=factor(value,
                      labels=c("no", "yes", "yes"),
                      levels=c(0,1,2))) |>
  uncount(weights=n) |>
  mutate(id=row_number(), .by=c(group, name)) |>
  pivot_wider(values_fill="no") |>
  select(-id)

data


# A tibble: 5 × 3
  group     common_carotid internal_carotid
  <chr>     <fct>          <fct>           
1 primary   yes            no              
2 secondary yes            yes             
3 secondary yes            no              
4 secondary no             no              
5 primary   no             yes


data |> 
  tbl_summary(
  by = group,
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_p()




Thank you, I have done that but the problem here is that you have your Fisher exact test on a group level and not per vessel. This might be done through the custom add_stat() function, however I have not yet succeeded in this.

Do you have the original data, not the summarised, one-hot-encoded version?

Thank you so much for helping. It gets a bit more complicated as the original data contains multiple vessels per cell, hence the one-hot-encoded solution as an attempt to keep the amount of cases (rows) the same. These are a couple of rows of the original data:
# A tibble: 414 × 4 ID genesis_group Arteries Veins    <dbl> <chr>         <fct>    <chr> 1    34 Secondary     RCCA     LIJV  2   35 Secondary     LVA      LIJV  3    58 Primary       STA      NA    4    59 Primary       STA OA   NA    5    60 Primary       STA OA   NA

Thanks. Can you use dput(data) instead? And maybe paste the ouput into your edited question?

Thanks, didn't knew about dput as a function. I have used it and added a part of the original data to the question.

See the edit in my other answer. Are we getting closer?
